# Debug Django signal handlers

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use signals for the first time.  I have a model, `UserAlias`, and I want to execute some code after a `UserAlias` record is created.

`UserAlias` is defined in `aliases/models.py`
I created a `aliases/signals/handlers.py`. Here is that file's contents:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_init, post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from aliases.models import UserAlias

@receiver(post_init, sender=UserAlias)
def post_init_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    print('hello there from a signal')

@receiver(post_save, sender=UserAlias)
def post_save_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    print('hello there from a signal')

@receiver(post_delete, sender=UserAlias)
def post_delete_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    print('hello there from a signal')
```

But when I execute:

```
from aliases.models import *
newalias = UserAlias.objects.create(...omitted...)
```

I do not see any of my debug `print` statements execute.
What am I missing here?

UPDATED:

I moved the definitions of my `post_init_handler`, `post_save_handler` and `post_delete_handler` to my `aliases/models.py` file after the declaration of my `UserAlias` class.

Also my `post_init_handler` now looks like this:

```
@receiver(post_init, sender=UserAlias)
def post_init_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print(f'hello there from a signal {sender} {instance}')
```

I tried declaring it as Paaksing suggested ...

```
@receiver(post_init, sender=UserAlias)
def post_init_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print(f'hello there from a signal {created} {sender} {instance}')
```

But I would get this error:

```
TypeError: post_init_handler() missing 1 required positional argument: 'created'
```

UPDATE II:

The post_init handler does not have a `created` parameter.  The `created` parameter goes with the `post_save` handlers.  Like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=UserAlias)
def post_save_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        print(f'hello from post_save_handler( {sender}, {instance}, {created})')
```

Comment: The most probable error is that you didn't import the handlers file from anywhere, so Django doesn't knows it should run them

Comment: Where should I import my handlers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a `created` attr.

Consider adding `instance` if working with models that are user-like so you can manipulate them on the signals.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=UserAlias)
def post_save_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        print('hello there from a signal')
```

**Update:** As Red Cricket said, the `post_init` does not have a `created` instance, but works with `post_save` as expected.

In the django doc shows all the instances that you can work with each signal: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/

Comment: The `post_init` handler does not have a created parameter. The created parameter goes with the post_save handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You created your signals in a seperate module (which is good). You also need to import the module at the right direction to use them.

The Django documentation advices to put the signals inside your app config file.
You could do it for example like this.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myproject.app'

    def ready(self) -> None:
        import myproject.app.aliases/signals/handlers  # noqa
```